# Format numberfield to currency

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, formula

I have a SharePoint list and created a powerapp.

In the SharePoint list there is a field Kosten and the value 20 in powerapps looks like 20.0000000000000.

How can I change this to € 20,00 ?

Comment: Is it 20.000000000000 or 2.0000000000000? Also, you want to show this ( € 20,00) in powerapps or sharepoint list view?

Comment: It's 20.0000000000000 and i want to show € 20,00 in Powerapps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using the following syntax:

```
" € " & Text(Value(ThisItem.TotaalKosten; "en-US"); "[$-nl-NL]0,00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formula like:

```
"€" & Text(Round(20.43200000000000,2), "[$-fr-FR]# ###,##", "fr-FR")
```

**Output**: `€20,43`

**References**:

1. [Round, RoundDown, and RoundUp functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-round)
2. [Text function in Power Apps - Global Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-text#global-apps-1)

Comment: This causes an error which says that there are unexpected characters.

Comment: Try to use semicolon instead of comma, like: `"€" & Text(Round(20.43200000000000;2); "[$-fr-FR]# ###,##"; "fr-FR")`

Comment: No, the error An operator is expected appears.